# Jackson deserialize to POJO without annotations

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have this json generated and i want to deserialize to List of POJOs

```
{
"members":
    [
      {"id":"947","route":"123","milkNo":"Z5623","nationalId":"65326812","firstName":"Server","otherName":"Farmer","country":"Kenya","county":"Nyandarua","address":"South Kinangop","phone1":"0752365258","phone2":"0712456321","email":"yunus.awse@gmail.com","sent":"0","remoteServer":1,"createdAt":"2015-10-21 11:17:31","updatedAt":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"}],

 "milkPayment":
     [
        {"id":"3","memberNo":"1","quantity":"40","price":"36","amount":"1437.5","deductions":"16390","payable":"-14952.5","date":"2015-10-16","remoteServer":1,"createdAt":"2015-10-16 10:26:10"}
     ],
 "advancePayment":[]
}
```

How can I extract only `members` array part so that I can feed it in the following code to get List of Member

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

List<Member> newMemberDeductions = objectMapper.readValue(a, objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Member.class));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this by using `JsonNode` (traversing required keys from json).Try this:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode node = objectMapper.readTree(new File("D:/Tests/sample.txt"));
node = node.findValue("members");
List<Member> newMemberDeductions = objectMapper.readValue(node.toString(), objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Member.class));
```

Here I put your json as file in `D:/Tests/sample.txt`